# Why does debian unstable prefer to install cgmanager?

Tags: debian, systemd, cgroups

I used `debootstrap` and `systemd-nspawn` to boot a container of Debian Unstable.  The host system was Debian Jessie.

`systemctl` shows the container has a failed service, `cgproxy`.  (Installing `cgmanager` on the host did not help, despite running a `cgmanager` daemon).

If I ask `apt-get` about removing `cgmanager` from the container, it says to remove `systemd-shim` and install `systemd-sysv`.  But `aptitude` suggests `systemd-shim` was the preferred alternative.

```
$ aptitude why cgmanager
i   systemd        Recommends libpam-systemd                        
i A libpam-systemd Depends    systemd-shim (>= 10-3~) | systemd-sysv
i A systemd-shim   Depends    cgmanager (>= 0.32)
```

- What specifically does `libpam-systemd` depend on, which can be provided by either one of `systemd-shim` or `systemd-sysv`??  The description for `systemd-sysv` only says it has "manual pages and links needed for systemd to replace sysvinit".
- Why does the `libpam-systemd` package prefer `systemd-shim` over `systemd-sysv`?
- If I switched it so I hadn't indirectly installed `systemd-shim` and thus `cgmanager`, am I going to be losing any expected functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What specifically does libpam-systemd depend on, which can be provided by either one of systemd-shim or systemd-sysv?? The description for systemd-sysv only says it has "manual pages and links needed for systemd to replace sysvinit".

I think it's the `systemd-` part :-P.

`libpam-systemd` is designed to work on a system which was booted with `systemd`.  Alternatively, if it boots using a different init system, it will work with systemd-[shim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)).

You were misled somewhat by the name `systemd-sysv`.  It doesn't just provide backwards compatibility for user programs.  It also sets `systemd` as the default init system loaded by the kernel, by creating a symlink from `/sbin/init` to `/lib/systemd/systemd`.

The `libpam-systemd` package dependencies are assuming that the OS is booted with `systemd` if and only if systemd is the default init system.

**CONCLUSION:** When you want to install systemd in Debian, you generally want to install the systemd-sysv package.

The real reason you're confused is that you booted the container using `systemd-nspawn`.  I think `systemd-nspawn` searches for the init system in the usual places, *and then falls back to the `/lib/systemd/systemd`*.

If you'd tried to boot this install using the Linux kernel e.g. in a virtual machine, you would have noticed that you hadn't set up default init system

```
    if (!try_to_run_init_process("/sbin/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/etc/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/sh"))
        return 0;

    panic("No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. "
"See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.");
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.11/init/main.c#L990

> Why does the libpam-systemd package prefer systemd-shim over systemd-sysv?

Presumably some software packages depend on libpam-systemd.  When it's pulled in as a dependency, it's assumed that you don't want systemd-sysv installed if it isn't already marked as such.  Doing so would change your init system!  Instead, it's preferred to install the compatibility shim.

> If I switched it so I hadn't indirectly installed systemd-shim and thus cgmanager, am I going to be losing any expected functionality?

Nope.